# Rubbery chatter sensation in drivetrain

Tags: drivetrain

I have a 1x 9s setup and am a strong rider, I ride as a courier everyday.

I recently set this up with 2nd hand parts and built the wheels myself. I noticed some slight play (wouldn't really say play, just a very slight delay with engagement) in the freehub but everything else is normal.

It's not all the time, but I can feel a shudder in the pedals, even at low speeds, like when the fender is rubbing the tyre and gives you a sensation of dragging rubber.

It's happened on my previous wheel too before some of the pawls gave up.

Comment: So your wheel's hub was a second hand part?  Sounds like it might be anything from slightly worn through to impending failure.  Or its possible the pawls are blocked with grease and not fully engaging.

Comment: What's the condition and wear on the chain and cassette ?  Did you redeploy used ones?

Comment: It sounds like it might be related to the chain.  Either worn chain/sprocket, or a derailer is not centered over its sprocket and the chain is rubbing.

Comment: I had a new chain on a slightly used cassette, I will try indexing it

Comment: Does the shudder occur with the same gear ratio?  Does the shudder occur at the same cadence (regardless of speed)?